# Oracle Fetch out of Sequence ORA-01002

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

This query is failing randomly in production upon fetch of next record from the cursor, the error being `ORA-01002`.

```
SELECT * FROM CHDR 
WHERE ( ( CHDR.LOAD = :1 ) AND ( ( CHDR.STATUS >= :2 ) AND ( CHDR.STATUS < :3 ) ) ) 
ORDER BY CHDR.PKT ASC
```

What could be the reason for this and what could i do to diagnose this well?

This is not even a select for update query.

Comment: Where this query is run ? In Java code, in PL/SQL procedure ? Perhaps the code that uses the query is trying to fetch a record from the cursor after the last row has been retrieved, or is trying to rebing placeholders then fetch without reexecutiing the statement.

Comment: ORA-01002 is nothing to do with the query itself. It indicates a clash with some other process. So you need to provide the whole program which contains this cursor and details of the wider context which calls this program.

Comment: By the way, you don't need any of those brackets.